# How to account for remainder in forecasting?

Tags: forecasting

I've done an STL decomposition of a time series. While trend accounts for major variations, remainder has a "cyclical" setup.

I want to know what other forecasting methods I can apply to maximize data explanation via trend and seasonality and would like to see it decomposed. I only know of ETS as a tool.

I'm a fresher in the world of statistics. Help appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What makes you say that the remainder has a "cyclical" setup? Eyeballing or some analysis?

Comment: Visual interpretation of remainder section lead to cyclical comment.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the first half of the series has much lower variance than 2013-on. Have you tried to only use 2013-on with the same stl decomposition? You could also try a classic decomposition & X-12 decomposition, see this chapter for an explanation and R code: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6